# How to fetch 3 column values together from a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, combobox

I have a table named CrewMembers which have 3 columns-FirstName,MiddleName and LastName.
I want to fetch the values of these 3 columns together using entity framework in a combobox in this format-

LastName,FirstName MiddleName

Here is the code for the same-

```
     public IEnumerable GetCrewMember()
     {
        SASEntities db = DataContextFactory.GetSASEntitiesDataContext();
         return (from cm in db.CrewMember
               select
                 cm.LastName + "," +
                  cm.FirstName +" "+
                  cm.FullName
           ).ToList();
       }
```

Now when I execute the code,I get only those names in the combobox which have all three values in the table but my MiddleName column can be left Null.Hence,I am not getting full names of those records which doesn't have a MiddleName.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
public IEnumerable GetCrewMember()
{
     SASEntities db = DataContextFactory.GetSASEntitiesDataContext();

     return (from cm in db.CrewMember
             select new 
             {
                  CompleteName = cm.LastName + "," 
                                  + cm.FirstName +" "
                                  + cm.FullName
             }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: what is your problem then? the above query (including your's) is going to fetch all the records from CrewMember table immaterial whether any of the three columns has null data or not

Comment: No,your query just adds one more issue to the whole thing because it is not displaying all those names which have Middle name as null and moreover I am getting the values in combobox as CompleteName="full name"

Comment: do one thing, show how you are binding your combobox. Besides, db.CrewMember is going to fetch all the data, that is for sure, rest all i can say, u are missing something somewher